invalid message executing safeitem.recipients.add on windows server system
have redemption installed on a Windows Server 2022 (tried Windows Server 2019 as well).  In our code, we create the OLE object (no issues), add attachment(s), again no issues, then we call the safeitem.recipients.add( 'emailaddress@something.com' ).  This fails and shows "invalid message" as the failure.
We we use the code on a non-server system, ie: Windows 10, Windows 11, no issues.  Any ideas?
Thanks in advance
David Gauthier
searched web, cannot find any issues related to this
code snippet;
int li_ret

long i, ll_pos0, ll_pos
long llReturn

string ls_recipient, ls_error_message

OLEObject oleSafeItem
OLEObject lole_session, lole_msg,  lole_attach

is_redemption_error_message = ''////CMD 8.18.2017 WO-9408 - SMARTsoft Compatibility Test 

TRY

    lole_session = create oleobject
    llReturn =  lole_session.ConnectToNewObject("outlook.application")
    yield()                   

    if llReturn = 0 then
        
        oleobject ole_namespace
        ole_namespace = lole_session.GetNamespace('MAPI')
        ole_namespace.Logon
        
        oleSafeItem = CREATE OLEObject
        llReturn = oleSafeItem.ConnectToNewObject( "Redemption.SafeMailItem") 
        yield()                   
        
        if llReturn = 0 then
            
            lole_msg = CREATE OLEObject
            lole_msg = lole_session.CreateItem(0)
            yield()                   
            oleSafeItem.Item = lole_msg
            
            lole_attach = oleSafeItem.Attachments
            for i = 1 to upperbound( as_attachment, 1 )
                lole_attach.Add( as_attachment[i] )
            next
            
            ll_pos0 = 0
            ll_pos = 1
            DO WHILE ll_pos > 0 
                ll_pos = Pos ( as_recipient, ';' ,ll_pos0+1 )
                IF ll_pos = 0 THEN
                    ls_recipient = Mid(as_recipient, ll_pos0+1)
                ELSE
                    ls_recipient = Mid(as_recipient, ll_pos0+1, ll_pos - ll_pos0 - 1)
                    ll_pos0 = ll_pos
                END IF
                oleSafeItem.Recipients.Add(ls_recipient)  <-- point of failure BUT only on a Windows Server system, as in using RDP session
            LOOP
            oleSafeItem.Recipients.ResolveAll


What is the exact error message?

I use a try catch, it is an ole error and the error message shows the name of the event called and the error itself.  In this case "Receiptients.Add - invalid message"

The error means SafeMailItem.Item property is not set. What is the relevant snippet of your code that creates and initializes the SafeMailItem object?

oleSafeItem = CREATE OLEObject
llReturn = oleSafeItem.ConnectToNewObject( "Redemption.SafeMailItem")
lole_msg = CREATE OLEObject
lole_msg = lole_session.CreateItem(0)
ll_pos0 = 0
ll_pos = 1
DO WHILE ll_pos > 0
ll_pos = Pos ( as_recipient, ';' ,ll_pos0+1 )
IF ll_pos = 0 THEN
ls_recipient = Mid(as_recipient, ll_pos0+1)
ELSE
ls_recipient = Mid(as_recipient, ll_pos0+1, ll_pos - ll_pos0 - 1)
ll_pos0 = ll_pos
END IF
oleSafeItem.Recipients.Add(ls_recipient)
LOOP

is it possible to attach a file with the all of the relevant code.  The comment section was extremely limiting

You can modify your original question and add code to it

original question revised to include code snippet.  Thank you

Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com, and i will send you the debug version of Redemption.
